# Why can't some types (with array notation) be used as return type in C without typedef?

Tags: c++, c

While messing around with the type syntax, I noticed this is legal :

```
typedef int *((* T)[10]);

T fun(){
  return 0;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  //int c = fun(); // (1)
  return 0;
}
```

...And if you uncomment `(1)`, then you get an error message of this kind (GCC / Clang) : "`error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'T' (aka 'int *((*)[10])')`" (Normal so far). Notice however the "`aka`" that points out the type is an alias of `int *((*)[10])` and not simply `int ***`

However, It seems impossible to declare a function with this type without using a typedef :

```
int *((*)[10]) fun(){ // The compiler does not approve
  return 0;
};

int *((* fun2)[10]) (){ // The compiler does not approve either
  return 0;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  //int c = fun(); // (1)
  return 0;
}
```

...Then I was wondering why ?
(the question is for the C language, but it looks like it's the same for C++)

Comment: `int *((* fun2)[10]) ()` -> `int *((* fun2() )[10])`. It's the `fun2` that's a function, not array elements.

Comment: [cdecl helps here](https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+f+as+function+returning+pointer+to+array+10+of+pointer+to+int).  `declare f as function returning pointer to array 10 of pointer to int` -> `int *(*f())[10]`

Comment: Not really. It requires knowing the answer, so it doesn't help find the answer.

Comment: @ikegami: It helped me anyway.  I could tell that the type `T` was `pointer to array 10 of pointer to int` and that we wanted a function returning this type, so I could work out the query to cdecl.  But I couldn't tell off the top of my head where the `[10]` ought to go, so I didn't already know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
int *((*fun())[10]) {
  return 0;
};
```

... Yup. You should probably stick to the typedef for the sake of readability :)

Comment: Oh boy why haven't I though about putting the full parameter list inside the parenthesis...

Comment: By the way, I completely agree. But it's for testing the edge cases of a code generation tool I'm developing...

Comment: If you use trailing return type syntax, it's not so bad: https://godbolt.org/z/zn1rr7v1Y . It's still ugly, but at least all of the type is in one location: `auto fun() -> int *((*)[10])`

Answer (score 3):

This type:

```
typedef int *((* T)[10]);
```

Is a pointer to an array of size 10 whose members are of type `int *`.  This is *not* the same as an `int ***`.

As for creating a function that returns this type, you would need this:

```
int *(*fun())[10] {
  return 0;
};
```

But using a `typedef` makes this much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The original

```
typedef int *((* T)[10])
```

can shed the outer parens:

```
typedef int *(* T)[10]
```

Or aligned with dbush's function:

```
typedef int *(*   T   )[10]
        int *(* fun() )[10]
```